# remove border from 3d model

Tags: model, 3d, outline, model-viewer

I have this code that displays a 3d model. There is a black outline around the model when user starts moving the object. how do i get rid of this black outline? this is my code:

```
    <model-viewer  id="testModel" style="width: 700px; height: 700px; outline: 0;border: none;box-shadow: none;outline-width: 0px;" src="B - Oshrat -  2- SF35OP2 - 2 PIPING LINES binary/H - Oshrat - SEAMLESS LES GALOON v7_Colorway 2.glb" alt="A 3D model of an astronaut" shadow-intensity="1"  ar ar-modes="webxr" auto-rotate camera-controls></model-viewer>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.js"></script>
  <script  nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer-legacy.js"></script>
```

this is my css:

```
    *:active{
  outline: 0;
  border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline-width: 0px;
}
*:focus{
    outline: 0;
  border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline-width: 0px;
}
*:visited{
    outline: 0;
  border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline-width: 0px;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMySL.png)

Comment: It seems to be unsupported at the moment, unless you do some javascript hacks, as the outline is default browser behavior when the element is focused, and this css is inside the shadow dom of the model viewer, so you can't control it from outside.

Answer (score 2):

Put

```
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/focus-visible@5.1.0/dist/focus-visible.js"></script>
```

In your HTML header.

Thats the fix accourding to https://github.com/google/model-viewer/pull/660

Answer (score 0):

It may be because outline: 0; should be outline: none;

Comment: How about removing shadow-intensity="1"?

Comment: The shadow intensity is a shadow within the model. But I gave it a try, and the black outline is still there.